# How can I detect a double tap on a certain cell in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can I detect a double tap on a certain cell in `UITableView`?

**i.e.** I want to perform one action if the user made a single touch and another if a user made a double touch? I also need to know an index path where the touch was made.

How can I achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean a double tap or a multi-touch?

Comment: just from a HIG standpoint, you might want to consider using an accessory button instead of requiring double tap? I don't know the usage scenario, but you might have to explain this one to your users.

Comment: The modern approach would be to use a UIGestureRecognizer. Add it in Interface Builder. You can set the number of taps. You connect the UIGestureRecognizer in a target/action way, as you would a button.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you do not want to create a subclass of `UITableView`, use a timer with the table view's `didSelectRowAtIndex:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //checking for double taps here
    if(tapCount == 1 && tapTimer != nil && tappedRow == indexPath.row){
        //double tap - Put your double tap code here
        [tapTimer invalidate];
        [self setTapTimer:nil];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Double Tap" message:@"You double-tapped the row" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else if(tapCount == 0){
        //This is the first tap. If there is no tap till tapTimer is fired, it is a single tap
        tapCount = tapCount + 1;
        tappedRow = indexPath.row;
        [self setTapTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(tapTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]];
    }
    else if(tappedRow != indexPath.row){
        //tap on new row
        tapCount = 0;
        if(tapTimer != nil){
            [tapTimer invalidate];
            [self setTapTimer:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (void)tapTimerFired:(NSTimer *)aTimer{
    //timer fired, there was a single tap on indexPath.row = tappedRow
    if(tapTimer != nil){
        tapCount = 0;
        tappedRow = -1;
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Would you mind posting more of your code. Where are you setting the tapTimer, tappedRow, and tapCount? Thanks!

Comment: Is it safe to set the timer to the magic number 0.2? Is that the usual time limit between taps of a double tap, and can that number change?

Comment: @jlstrecker no one would usually take more time than this for a double-tap. Just a random number I came up with after experimenting with a few.

Comment: I think there is a tapCount = 0; missing in the first if clause, just before (or maybe after is more precise?) showing the alert

Comment: Why is this better than a single tap and double tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: @ChuckKelly its not. Gesture recognizers were introduced in 2010. This answer is from 2009, a year before they were made available.

Answer (score 27):

Override in your `UITableView` class this method

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {

     if(((UITouch *)[touches anyObject]).tapCount == 2)
    {
    NSLog(@"DOUBLE TOUCH");
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain me how do I exactly override the method?
I created an object which inherits from UITableView and added a method you recommended. But this method doesn't get called. Thanks.

Comment: Not to necropost per se, but this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for - thanks! Only one gotcha for me. What if the UITableView in question is the one within the UITabBar's moreNavigationController? :(

Comment: You can also add this to your `UITableViewCell` class.

Answer (score 10):

In your `UITableView` subclass, do something like this:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch* touch in touches) {
        if (touch.tapCount == 2)
        {
            CGPoint where = [touch locationInView:self];
            NSIndexPath* ip = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:where];
            NSLog(@"double clicked index path: %@", ip);

            // do something useful with index path 'ip'
        }
    }

    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

First define:

```
int tapCount;
NSIndexPath *tableSelection;
```

as class level variables in the .h file and do all the necessary setting up. Then...

```
- (void)tableView(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    tableSelection = indexPath;
    tapCount++;

    switch (tapCount) {
        case 1: //single tap
            [self performSelector:@selector(singleTap) withObject: nil afterDelay: .4];
            break;
        case 2: //double tap
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(singleTap) object:nil];
            [self performSelector:@selector(doubleTap) withObject: nil];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Tap/multiTap

- (void)singleTap {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Single tap detected" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];   
    tapCount = 0;
}

- (void)doubleTap {
    NSUInteger row = [tableSelection row];
    companyName = [self.suppliers objectAtIndex:row]; 
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"DoubleTap" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    tapCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: you can simple `[self doubleTap];` instead of `[self performSelector:@selector(doubleTap) withObject: nil];` ;)

Comment: This code has a few syntax errors, tried to edit but for some strange reason was rejected: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2016633

Answer (score 6):

```
if([touch tapCount] == 1)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(singleTapRecevied) withObject:self afterDelay:0.3];

} else if ([touch tapCount] == 2)
  {        
    [TapEnableImageView cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(singleTapRecevied) object:self]; 
}
```

Use the performSelector to call a selector instead of using a timer. This solves the issue mentioned by @V1ru8.

Answer (score 6):

I chose to implement it by overriding the `UITableViewCell`.

**MyTableViewCell.h**

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, assign) int numberOfClicks;

@end
```

**MyTableViewCell.m**

```
@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
   self.numberOfClicks = [aTouch tapCount];
   [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   MyTableViewCell *myCell = (MyTableViewCell*) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   NSLog(@"clicks:%d", myCell.numberOfClicks);

   if (myCell.numberOfClicks == 2) {
       NSLog(@"Double clicked");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 solution from compare answers. No need any extensions, just add this code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    viewDidLoad()

    let doubleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap(sender:)))
    doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGestureRecognizer)

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture(sender:)))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: doubleTapGestureRecognizer)
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

func handleTapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: tableView)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}

func handleDoubleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: tableView)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you have to put any delay into the handleTapGesture method? I feel like handleTapGesture would execute before a second tap is detected and so handleTapGesture wouldn't have any time to fail. I'm kind of a noob though, so please explain if I'm not getting it correctly.

Comment: `require(toFail:)` makes it work https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-require

Answer (score 2):

Another answer

```
int touches;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  touches++;

    if(touches==2){
       //your action
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    touches=0;
}
```

Comment: best and shortest answer ever!

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to subclass `UITableView` and override whatever touch events are appropriate (`touchesBegan:withEvent`;, `touchesEnded:withEvent`, etc.)  Inspect the events to see how many touches there were, and do your custom behavior.  Don't forget to call through to `UITableView's` touch methods, or else you won't get the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

According to @lostInTransit I prepared code in Swift

```
var tapCount:Int = 0
var tapTimer:NSTimer?
var tappedRow:Int?

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //checking for double taps here
    if(tapCount == 1 && tapTimer != nil && tappedRow == indexPath.row){
        //double tap - Put your double tap code here
        tapTimer?.invalidate()
        tapTimer = nil
    }
    else if(tapCount == 0){
        //This is the first tap. If there is no tap till tapTimer is fired, it is a single tap
        tapCount = tapCount + 1;
        tappedRow = indexPath.row;
        tapTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "tapTimerFired:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    else if(tappedRow != indexPath.row){
        //tap on new row
        tapCount = 0;
        if(tapTimer != nil){
            tapTimer?.invalidate()
            tapTimer = nil
        }
    }
}

func tapTimerFired(aTimer:NSTimer){
//timer fired, there was a single tap on indexPath.row = tappedRow
    if(tapTimer != nil){
        tapCount = 0;
        tappedRow = -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: please see the comments below to see though while this solution worked for me, it still may not be a good idea.

An alternative to creating a subclass of `UITableView` or `UITableViewCell` (and to using a timer) would be just to extend the `UITableViewCell` class with a category, for example (using @oxigen's answer, in this case for the cell instead of the table):

```
@implementation UITableViewCell (DoubleTap)
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if(((UITouch *)[touches anyObject]).tapCount == 2)
    {
        NSLog(@"DOUBLE TOUCH");
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
@end
```

This way you don't have to go around renaming existing instances of `UITableViewCell` with the new class name (will extend all instances of the class).

Note that now `super` in this case (this being a category) doesn't refer to `UITableView` but to its super, `UITView`. But the actual method call to `touchesEnded:withEvent:` is in `UIResponder` (of which both `UITView` and `UITableViewCell` are subclasses), so there's no difference there.

Comment: Overwriting an existing method in a category may or may not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272451/overriding-methods-using-categories-in-objective-c

Comment: The original `UITableViewCell` isn't a category, so I don't see how this would have an effect here. But I've updated the last part of my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: How do you know that apple didn't break up the implementation in several categories?

Comment: when you write a category u also define it in your own file. So are you checking every header file before using a class? and even if a method is not defined in a category: it could be changed in any future version. Just never use categories for overriding.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I guess I'll delete this answer. Thanks for not marking down.

Comment: it is technical ok and should compile — but in this case this ist just not the full picture. not a reason to vote down IMO.

Comment: It worked for me in a brief test on one device, but I ended up using the solutions with timers myself.

Comment: I guess I would use a UITapGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

Here's my complete solution:

**CustomTableView.h**

```
//
//  CustomTableView.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableView : UITableView

    // Nothing needed here

@end
```

**CustomTableView.m**

```
//
//  CustomTableView.m
//

#import "CustomTableView.h"

@implementation CustomTableView


//
// Touch event ended
//
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    // For each event received
    for (UITouch * touch in touches) {

        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint: [touch locationInView:self] ];

        // One tap happened
        if([touch tapCount] == 1)
        {
            // Call the single tap method after a delay
            [self performSelector: @selector(singleTapReceived:)
                       withObject: indexPath
                       afterDelay: 0.3];
        }


        // Two taps happened
        else if ([touch tapCount] == 2)
        {
            // Cancel the delayed call to the single tap method
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: self
                                                     selector: @selector(singleTapReceived:)
                                                       object: indexPath ];

            // Call the double tap method instead
            [self performSelector: @selector(doubleTapReceived:)
                       withObject: indexPath ];
        }


    }

    // Pass the event to super
    [super touchesEnded: touches
              withEvent: event];

}


//
// Single Tap
//
-(void) singleTapReceived:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"singleTapReceived - row: %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}


//
// Double Tap
//
-(void) doubleTapReceived:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"doubleTapReceived - row: %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}



@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Improvement for [oxigen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031723/1763487) answer.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch.tapCount == 2) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        NSIndexPath *touchIndex = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
        if (touchIndex) {
            // Call some callback function and pass 'touchIndex'.
        }
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach has been tested to produce consistent results.

Lets keep it simple and straightforward. A `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your `UITableView` with `numberOfTapsRequired` set to **2** does the job efficiently and without interrupting the regular taps using cell selection with `didSelectRow`.

So, we have the recogniser creation:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tableViewCellDoubleTapped(_:)))
gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

and then we have the action:

```
@objc func tableViewCellDoubleTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = sender.location(in: sender.view)
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
        // Profit!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make and easy setup by using below code, this is the simplest logic for detect a double tap on a certain cell in UITableView.

```
var isDouble = false
var myTimer = Timer()
var secondsToCount = 0.0

@objc func updateTimer() {
    secondsToCount += 0.1
    isDouble = true
    if secondsToCount >= 0.5 {
        myTimer.invalidate()
        secondsToCount = 0.0
        
        isDouble = false
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myTimer.invalidate()
    myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: ["index":indexPath.row], repeats: true)
    
    if isDouble == true{
        //you can make logic for double click action here.
        print("DOUBLE CLICK EVENT FIRED in 0.5 Seconds ")

    }else{
        // this will not in use.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution is only works for UICollectionView or UITableView's cell.

First declare these variables

int number_of_clicks;

BOOL thread_started;

Then put this code in your didSelectItemAtIndexPath

```
++number_of_clicks;
if (!thread_started) {

    thread_started = YES;

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                                 0.25 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
                   dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

                       if (number_of_clicks == 1) {
                           ATLog(@"ONE");
                       }else if(number_of_clicks == 2){
                           ATLog(@"DOUBLE");
                       }

                       number_of_clicks = 0;
                       thread_started = NO;

                   });

        }
```

0.25 is the delay of between 2 clicks. I think 0.25 is perfect for detect this type of click. Now you can detect only one click and two clicks seperately. Good Luck