# How to detect double tap / touch event in tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

After a long but all in vain search, I am unable to detect the double tap / touch event in my tableview , actually want to call the detail view on double tap on any `TableViewCell` and in reality I don't even know how to do it at all .

This is my code so far…

In *viewDidLoad*

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.myTable addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

the **handleTapGesture** method is

```
- (void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
  if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {
      flag = true;
  }
}
```

and finally on touching or tapping the cell of tableview
the delegate method is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (flag == true)
    {
        DetailInvoicing *detail = [[DetailInvoicing alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailInvoicing" bundle:nil];
        detail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        detail.customerName = [customerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self presentViewController:detail animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

If I remove this flag condition new view is called on just single touch.
where am I wrong or is there any other way to do it .

Comment: Please replace `flag = true;` with `flag = YES;` and replace `flag == true` with just `flag`.

Comment: You can refer this link, hope your problem will be solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031254/how-can-i-detect-a-double-tap-on-a-certain-cell-in-uitableview Thanks

Comment: Why not present the view right where you detect the double-tap (in handleTapGesture)?

Comment: @nhgrif it works but not specifically on double tap… when i double tap nothing happened and then it called new view on third and some times on fourth tap …

Comment: @Anna i have to send the cell value to new view thats why using this way

Comment: @Zaibi, you can figure out the indexPath of the cell that was tapped in the gesture recognizer method itself.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924446/long-press-on-uitableview/3924965#3924965 for an example.

Comment: @Anna thanks a lot, this stack overflow link works for me.. thanks again.

Comment: @Anna and also your suggestion to call new view in (in handleTapGesture) is great. .. thanks

Comment: @Zaibi, May I suggest you post your updated code as an Answer to close this question.  Later, you'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a simple method, without using `UITapGestureRecognizer` nor implementing custom table view class.

```
@implementation MyTableViewController
NSTimeInterval lastClick;
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSTimeInterval now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] timeIntervalSince1970];
    if ((now - lastClick < 0.3) && [indexPath isEqual:lastIndexPath]) {
        // Double tap here
        NSLog(@"Double Tap!");
    }
    lastClick = now;
    lastIndexPath = indexPath;
}
@end
```

It is just view lines of code.

Answer (score 6):

Corrected For Swift 3.1

```
var lastClick: TimeInterval
var lastIndexPath: IndexPath? = nil

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let now: TimeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    if (now - lastClick < 0.3) &&
        (lastIndexPath?.row == indexPath.row ) {
         print("Double Tap!")
    }
    lastClick = now
    lastIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

Comment: can you please explain last two variable lastClick and lastIndexPath how you declare those two variable and where ?

Answer (score -1):

Try like this, in your customtableview class implement this below method:-

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches 
    withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
  // below numberofclick in integer type
   self.numberOfClicks = [aTouch tapCount];
 [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
 }
```

Now in your tableview delegate method (didSelectRowAtIndexPath). And then detect the numberOfclicks whether it is 2 or 1 and modified your condition accordingly. Below is the line of code which you can put in your delegate method to detect the number of taps pressed

```
   if (myCell.numberOfClicks == 2) {
   NSLog(@"Double clicked");   }}
```