# Issue in detecting double tap on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I want to perform one action if the user made a single touch and another if a user made a double touch on a UITableView Cell.

I tried multiple approaches mentioned in this question.

[How can I detect a double tap on a certain cell in UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031254/how-can-i-detect-a-double-tap-on-a-certain-cell-in-uitableview)

But every approach, I cannot distinguish single tap and double correctly. What I meant is, in each double tap, it happens a single tap also. So, double tap happens, every time single tap action also fired.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
FeedCell *myCell = (FeedCell*) [self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"clicks:%d", myCell.numberOfClicks);

if (myCell.numberOfClicks == 2) {
    NSLog(@"Double clicked");
}
else{

    NSLog(@"Single tap");
}
}
```

What should be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Use Long press gesture

Comment: Where do you increase the value of numberOfClicks? Where do you capture the double tap?

Comment: in CustomTableViewCell

Comment: - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    self.numberOfClicks = [aTouch tapCount];
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to don't used `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` while you want `double tap` action. Used `single TapGesture` that replace with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. whatever code you wrote in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, that will write in  `single tap` selector method.

**Example** : Implement Single and Double gesture like as below.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doSingleTap)] autorelease];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doDoubleTap)] autorelease];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2; 
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

Comment: Simple method. Works for me. Thanks

Comment: It even works on a MapView with no additional complexity like timers, extra global variables and so on...

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer - your single tap will handle on timer fire method.
Put your single tap action here

```
- (void)tapTimerFired:(NSTimer *)aTimer{
    //timer fired, there was a single tap on indexPath.row = tappedRow
    if(tapTimer != nil){
        tapCount = 0;
        tappedRow = -1;
    }
}
```

and double-tap will handle in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` exactly as showed:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //checking for double taps here
    if(tapCount == 1 && tapTimer != nil && tappedRow == indexPath.row){
        //double tap - Put your double tap code here
        [tapTimer invalidate];
        [self setTapTimer:nil];
    }
    else if(tapCount == 0){
        //This is the first tap. If there is no tap till tapTimer is fired, it is a single tap
        tapCount = tapCount + 1;
        tappedRow = indexPath.row;
        [self setTapTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(tapTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]];
    }
    else if(tappedRow != indexPath.row){
        //tap on new row
        tapCount = 0;
        if(tapTimer != nil){
            [tapTimer invalidate];
            [self setTapTimer:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to declare two properties

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger tapCount;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger tappedRow;
```

This is fully working snippet.